# How to convert a string to callable

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, cross-validation

I have created a string array and called a method with that array along with Train, test data. The purpose of the method is to find Kfold results of each algorithm specifies in the array. Everything works fine except in *cross_val_score(model,X,y)*, it considers the *model* variable as a simple string instead of a callable model. If I put it like this *cross_val_score(RandomForestClassifier(),X,y)* it works perfectly fine. Now, how to convert the string *model* to a callable model. I am new to ML and I may not be able to make you understand the problem properly. Please let me know if you have any question. Thank you.

```
strarray = ['RandomForestClassifier()','LogisticRegression()','SVC()']
def checkall(array,X,y,Kfold):
  for model in strarray:
    values = cross_val_score(model,X,y)
    print(values)
checkall(strarray,X,y,5)
```

Comment: You can simply change the values stored in the `strarray` to simply store either the model name or the initialized model: `[RandomForestClassifier(), LogisticRegression(), SVC()]`.

Comment: it worked. you can post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the values stored in the `strarray` variable to simply store either the model name or the initialized model:

```py
strarray = [RandomForestClassifier(), LogisticRegression(), SVC()]

def checkall(array,X,y,Kfold):
    for model in strarray:
        values = cross_val_score(model,X,y)
        print(values)

checkall(strarray,X,y,5)
```